# Spock stubbing RestTemplate works when breakpoint is added

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, stub

I am writing an unit test in Spock and trying to stub `RestTemplate.postForEntity()` but seeing a weird issue where the stubs only works when I add a breakpoint and evaluate the expression. It doesnt work and calls the `postForEntity()` method when run normally.

Here is my implementation.

Test:

```
def "AuthTokenRequest"() {
    given:
    def url = "https://authEndpoint"
    def map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()
    RestTemplate restTemplate = GroovySpy(global: true)
    restTemplate.postForEntity(*_) >> new ResponseEntity(new AuthResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)

    when:
    def responseEntity = client.authTokenRequest(url, map)

    then:
    responseEntity == response
}
```

Method making the HTTP request:

```
public AuthResponse authTokenRequest(String url, MultiValueMap map) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, createAuthEntity(map), AuthResponse.class);
    return responseEntity.getBody()?:null
    }
```

When I run this test, I get a `java.net.UnknownHostException` exception because `https://authEndpoint` doesnt point anywhere which also proves that `postEntity()` is not being stubbed.

When I put a breakpoint on `ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, createAuthEntity(map), AuthResponse.class);` and evaluate the expression, I get the stubbed response.

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Just making sure, but the code under test is also written in Groovy and not Java, right?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings The code under test is also written in Groovy. I ended up injecting RestTemplate as a dependency to this class to make it more testable but if you have thoughts on how to do this on the code I pasted, that would be really helpful.

Comment: How are you running the tests? Using an IDE? They run fine for me, without any breakpoint, when I run them with gradle using `./gradlew clean build`.  You can find the working code on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/java-demo/tree/spock-groovy-spy)